# jQuery plugin letter-fx - add setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded the jQuery plugin letter-fx (http://tuxsudo.com/code/project/letterfx) and really like what it can do.

However, on my landing page I'm trying to make the different paragraphs appear in sequence. I thought the best way to do that is to delay each paragraph with setTimeout()

I'm a JS/jQuery novice and hoping someone can help me out. Here's the code I have thus far:

```js
$(function(fx1){
 
 $(".fx1").letterfx({"fx":"fade","backwards":false,"timing":50,"fx_duration":"1000ms","letter_end":"restore","element_end":"stay"});

});

$(function(){
 setTimeout(fx1,3000);
});
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. To use `setTimeout` you need to pass a function as first param.

```
$(function(){

    var applyAnimation =  function(){
        $(".fx1").letterfx({"fx":"fade","backwards":false,"timing":50,"fx_duration":"1000ms","letter_end":"restore","element_end":"stay"});
    };

    setTimeout(applyAnimation,3000);
});
```

Comment: Sorry man, no luck with this code.  You can see the demo I'm working on here ... http://www.jameszedd.com/demos/reflexology/kira_index.html

First para has the letter-fx applied to it but I can't get the delay until after the CSS animation of the div.

Comment: See how the div fades in through CSS animation? And the first paragraph reveals itself? That's what I'm trying to delay. (BTW, I'm viewing the demo page through Chrome)

Comment: I've just run the setTimeout call for the function that I provided from browser console and the animation indeed started after 3 seconds ... is not it what you want?

Comment: Hmm ... I must still be missing something. Any chance you can set up a fiddle? Sorry but I'm really lost on this!

Comment: Okay. I re-tested your code and it did work! I appreciate your help on this. All I have to do now is get the letters to not appear when the screen opens and appear when the animation starts.